# moving my app's backend from Firebase to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, backend

What's the best way to migrate from Firebase to AWS? I want to change the service because Ive read that AWS is way better than Firebase for apps that require a large user base. What would you recommend? I was using almost everything on Firebase (Login, Database, Storage).

Comment: It seems like that it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567142/migrating-firebase-users-to-aws-cognito) in `Mar'18`. Though this is an older question, and should have been answered here still if someone end up here, he/she can be directed to the version with solution (both in `question and the approved answer`).

Answer (score 3):

As far as my knowledge, there is no straight forward solution to migrate the data from Firebase to AWS.

My suggestion would be export the data from Firebase and write a script in your favourite language and upload it in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

See, Firebase is based on Google Cloud Platform(GCP) and you cannot just directly shift from Firebase to AWS. For this task, you may talk to Google Cloud support and ask them about this. Well, I don't think that this would even work as AWS and Firebase are a lot different and so, people are told to choose their first cloud service wisely.